# Error : org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: 'D:\Code\MSCVE\ADVISORIES' is not under version control

Tags: java, svnkit

```
SVNURL url1 = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("file:///E:/SVN/IDS/MSCVE")                System.out.println("*************"); String dstPath1="D:/code/MSCVE";
        //String dstPath3="D:/code/MSCVE";
        String dstPath3="D:\\Code\\MSCVE\\ADVISORIES";
        String destpath="D:/myworkingcopy1/CVE-2011-1880.doc";
        String dstPath2="file:///E:/SVN/IDS/MSCVE/CVE-2011-1284.doc";
SVNClientManager cm = SVNClientManager.newInstance();

        SVNCommitClient cc = cm.getCommitClient();
        System.out.println("CCCCCCCCCC");
        //System.out.println("cc" + cc.getOptions());
        System.out.println("before commiting");
        cc.doCommit(new File[] { new File(dstPath3) }, false,
                "XML file are added in the MSCVE folder.........added three more cve numbers in the 1284 doc ", false, true);
        //cc.doCommit(new File[] {"C:/Users/Kiran.Chinnapelli/AppData/Roaming/Subversion"}, false, "commiting", null, null, false, false, SVNDepth.FILES);
```

Error:

> org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: 'D:\Code\MSCVE\ADVISORIES' is not under version control

Comment: Its is throwing an error messge at                                  cc.doCommit(new File[] { new File(dstPath3) }, false, 
                "XML file are added in the MSCVE folder.........added three more cve numbers",1284 doc ", false, true);

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the folder named 'ADVISORIES' then you need to add it to SVN first.
Then try adding/updating files next.

Comment: I already created advisories folder in SVN and checkout in to my local machine... while commiting I am giving the same localmachine avdisories folder path... and its shwoing not under version control